# How to deploy Play on Amazon Beanstalk keeping /public editable for a single page application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ember.js, deployment, playframework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking for alternative methods of deploying a Play application to Elastic Beanstalk.  It is a single page app that relies on Ember.js.  It would be nice to be able to edit the the contents of the /public folder so I don't need to rebuild the docker image every time something is fixed on the Ember side that doesn't affect the Play app itself.

I am currently using sbt's `docker:stage` command and zipping the generated docker folder along with this Dockerfile and Dockerrun.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:latest
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD stage /
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
EXPOSE 9000
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myapp", "-Dconfig.resource=application-prod.conf"]
CMD []
```

**Dockerrun**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [{ "ContainerPort": "9000" }],
    "Volumes": []
}
```

Once I zip the file I upload it using Beanstalk console.  But this involves rebuilding the app every time a typo is fixed on the front end.  It is annoying because it means all the updated front end code has to wait until I get a chance to push it up so the boss can view it and give feedback.  It would be nice if there was a way to have the /public folder (Play just serves /public/index.html) accessible so the front end dev could access it directly for his edits.

Ideally I would like some method that can be used for both development and production.  I don't know the requirements imposed by Beanstalk so it can properly spin up extra instances of the app when needed.  Maybe something where when the instance starts it does git pull on the backend repo and git pull on the front end repo, then runs my custom build script for ember to generate the /dist folder and move into Play's /public folder and create gzips of each file.  Then start the play app.  Then let the front end Dev ssh into the development instance and do git pull and ember build as needed for his edits.

It would also be nice for the development server for the Play server to be run using `run` or `~run` so I can just do git pull and have it rebuild the backend.

Or maybe I am approaching this in the completely wrong way.  I have never done any of this before so I am sort of guessing my way through all of it.

Thanks for any suggestions and pointers in the correct direction.

Adam

**Edit**

Since we are really only using Play as a RESTful API would it be better to just run a nginx/Apache server on something like EC2 then use Beanstalk to handle the Play App without it serving any content besides API calls.  I would assume the EC2 nginx could be pretty tiny since only the first access would pull files from the http server.  After that it is all API calls.  Then we run the Play app from Beanstalk so it can handle load balancing for the API.  This at least saves me from rebuilding the image for front end edits.  Would this be a more correct setup?

Comment: In "production" mode Play packages all the assets (the public folder) in a jar, so I don think you can change it. You may try to add some http server like nginx or apache and make it serve the static files instead of Play, and proxy other requests to Play: not sure how hard this would be using docker...

Comment: That might be a better method, since we are really only using Play as a RESTful API.  All the files are just static js/css files which make API calls for data.  At that point it might be better to just run a single EC2 instance of nginx/apache and just use beanstalk to host the API.  Since that is the part that would get bogged down by requests and need new instances.   I'll look into it, thanks @Salem